# JVM arguments not being passed to java application at run time

Tags: java, jmx, jvm-arguments

I try to give VM parameters (jmx parameters)  to run a jar file. For some reason, the VM parameters configured not being passed to the java application at run time (log statement in main method confirms that aswell). Application launches successfully but unable to access jmx service. It all works fine with Intellij though.

```
JVM_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost \

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8020 \

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8021 \

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

eval "java $JVM_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar target/shopfront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

I tried to access jmx via visual vm but I am unsuccessful.
Version: Java 11

I expect to access jmx via visual client

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you check the actual commandline of that process to see if the parameters are there? Check `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

Comment: What is the interpreter for the above code snippet? Bash? cmd? Powershell? Does it support setting the variable the way you intend to? You could echo the variable and the full command before executing them.

Comment: the above command works fine. It was a wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

The above script works fine. It is bash script

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).